# How can I solve peak by using simulink in matlab?

Tags: matlab, simulink

How to know the number of maximum and minimum peaks in a signal, and each peak its value, with input of random and real-time signal using simulink in matlab?

Comment: Be a little more precise. A screenshot of a minimal example would help also.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/dsp/ref/peakfinder.html